# How do I climb stairs?

Tags: xcom-2

Sometimes I see things like stairs and such with an up arrow, seems to me like I should be able to climb these.

However my soldiers don't like walking stairs (probably lazy or something) and instead move one tile when I try to order them up.

How do I motivate them to climb the stairs?

Comment: Your soldiers may be Daleks in disguise. Proceed with caution.

Comment: They do seem to be about as good a shot.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use your mouse wheel to scroll up floors, then you can set a target destination on somewhere on that floor.

Answer (score 32):

You have two options:

- **Mouse**: A mouse with a scroll wheel will allow you to scroll up and down and change the elevation you want.

  - <kbd>MWHEELUP</kbd>(scroll up) - Toggle elevation up
  - <kbd>MWHEELDOWN</kbd>(scroll down) - Toggle elevation down
- **Keyboard**: You can use the keyboard buttons (default control scheme)

  - <kbd>F</kbd> - Toggle elevation up
  - <kbd>C</kbd>- Toggle elevation down

Comment: For console, its up and down on the D-Pad to view different elevations.